# Bootstrap3 - 5 columns desktop tablet and stack in mobile inside a form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to achieve to have 1 input field, 3 dropdown boxes and one submit button in 5 columns horizontal view inside a form for desktop and tablet view. In mobile view, it should stack with a margin of each field (left or right in desktop or tablet view) and top or bottom on mobile view.

I tried the following [on my site](http://www.volcanodeinvierno.com/)

```
<div class="row">           
    <div class="col-sm-4"><input placeholder="' . JText::_('COM_BT_MEDIA_ENTER_YOUR_KEYWORD') . '" type="text" name="filter_search" id="filter_search" value="' . $app->input->getString('filter_search') . '" title="' . JText::_('Search') . '" /></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">' . $filterType . '</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">' . $filterOrdering . '</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">' . $filterDirection . '</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.submit();">' . JText::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT') . '</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the fields or dropdown show stack...

Any ideas on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To learn bootstrap, make [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) site your best friend.

To see a demo of your solution look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/coozin/wtw6g2n7/1/)

Your html elements need to be floated left to stay inline. Heres the HTML solution:

```
<div class="row">           
<div class="col-sm-4 left">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder text">
</div>
<div class="dropdown col-sm-2 left">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
       Dropdown
       <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown col-sm-2 left ">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown col-sm-2 left">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 left ">
       <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.left{
    float: left; 
}
```

Comment: thanks - but when they are stack they have no margin top or bottom and stick too close to eachother to press them

Comment: you add a class to the div `class="my-class"`and in the css you adjust your margins how you want: `.my-class{margin: 20px;}`